# How to know whether replace success or fail?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

```
bool rep = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Replace(textBox1.Text, 
                                     textBox2.Text, 
                                     Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, 
                                     Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, 
                                     false, 
                                     Type.Missing, 
                                     Type.Missing, 
                                     Type.Missing);
```

Comment: It is always a success until and unless you have given a wrong criteria to replace. In that case it will fail.

Comment: But it returns true in all cases...

Comment: Do you actually want to know 'how many replacements were made' ?

Comment: No, If replacement happened in a sheet i need that sheet name

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(i);

                    bool rep = false;

                    rep = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    if (rep == true)
                    {
                        SheetsArray.Add(xlWorkSheet.Name);
                    }
                }

Comment: I am trying to execute the above code but it returns all sheets names in a work book irrespective of replacements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works fine:

```
   Excel.Range Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

  currentFind =  Range .Find(textBox1.Text,                      Type.Missing,Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,               Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,                             Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,false,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


   if (currentFind!=null)
   {

        SheetsArray.Add(xlWorkSheet.Name);
   }
```

Comment: Yes, it's basically my answer... But you said that you wanted to replace the text AND to know if it was there. In this way you only find out whether the string is found in your shhets or not.

Comment: In your answer you set the xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find to bool but it returns Range...

Comment: In the edit there is a != null that I forgot in copying from VS... But I still do not understand if you want to replace something or not

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way. The Replace method of Range does always return true if the parameters are correct. The only thing that I know you could do is to first look for occurrences of your text, and then replace it. Definitely not optimized, but I can't think of something else.

```
bool rep = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(textBox1.Text, 
                                  Type.Missing,
                                  Type.Missing, 
                                  Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, 
                                  Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                                  Type.Missing, 
                                  false, 
                                  Type.Missing, 
                                  Type.Missing) != null;
if (rep)
           xlWorkSheet.Cells.Replace(textBox1.Text, 
                                     textBox2.Text, 
                                     Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, 
                                     Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, 
                                     false, 
                                     Type.Missing, 
                                     Type.Missing, 
                                     Type.Missing);
```